# Best idea to pass variables from a href link

Tags: php, forms, variables

I have a href link, and I would like to pass some variables without using them in a link, what is the best idea?

```
<a href="Files/download.php?file=fileName">Click</a>
```

I would like to get these variables into my download.php page to update them into my database table:

```
timestamp
downloads
hits
views
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="Files/download.php?file=fileName" >Click</a>
```

Its all depend on your situation how to do it because there are lots of ways to do this

1) if you dont want to show the parameters to user, then you can encrypt them & add them in URL.
2) if you dont want parameters in URL, then you can create hidden input tags for all parameters & then using POST method submit that form on HREF click or store the values in session

```
<form id='hidden_form' action='Files/download.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='timestamp' value='some value' >
<input type='hidden' name='downloads' value='some value' >
<input type='hidden' name='hits' value='some value' >
<input type='hidden' name='views' value='some value' >
```

```
$_SESSION['timestamp']  = '<some value>';
$_SESSION['downloads']  = '<some value>';
$_SESSION['hits']   = '<some value>';
$_SESSION['views']  = '<some value>';
```

Comment: are there any challenges to use session? for example session stolen

Comment: Sessions are significantly safer than, say, cookies. But it is still possible to steal a session and thus the hacker will have total access to whatever is in that session. Some ways to avoid this are IP Checking  & using a nonce. Typically with a nonce, you have a per-page "token" so that each page checks that the last page's nonce matches what it has stored.

Answer (score 0):

Using a link, you don't have much flexibility. You can really only pass them through the url.

You could do more however if this was a form, and these variables were passed as POST data. Then they would be hidden to the user and not present in the url. You could use hidden inputs:

```
<input type='hidden' name='myVariable' value='5' />
```

You could also store them in a `$_SESSION` but it's difficult to say what's best for your situation without context.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. He asked how to pass variables into another PHP page without putting them in a link. I gave two alternatives.

Comment: thanks man, I upvoted, are there any challenges to use session? for example session stolen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use href link then use the following.

```
<a href="Files/download.php?file=fileName&timestamp=value&downloads=value&hits=value&views=value">Click</a>
```

Comment: I do not want to use parameters in links